# What is the name of the appendage that mantis shrimp use to rub their eyes?

Tags: zoology, ethology, anatomy

In this [short clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cG1wzGbBnsg), you can see the mantis shrimp using some sort of feathery arm/claw to rub its eyes. Looking at a diagram [here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_82GUbxEh8kI/TSWY6qkab_I/AAAAAAAAACU/qSjy1DsmwgI/s1600/Alek4.png), it appears possibly that it's using maxillipeds. Someone with knowledge of crustaceans (the behavior is probably not unique to mantis shrimp) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mantis shrimp use their first maxillipeds for grooming ([maxilliped=modified appendage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendage)), which is [specialized for this purpose](http://arthropoda.southernfriedscience.com/?p=3526). Details and a picture of the organ can be found in the link. The second maxilliped is their famous specialized organ for [striking or spearing prey with enormous force](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-ahuZEvWH8). More about their [raptoral appendage](http://arthropoda.southernfriedscience.com/?p=801), with links to further references. Mantis shrimp also have very complex eyes, described as ["...the most complicated visual system of any animal on Earth"](http://www.popsci.com/scitech/article/2008-03/eye-mantis-shrimp). Their eyes can see a range from ultraviolet to infra-red and has specialized regions for observing motion, form, depth, and color. More on Mantis shrimp eyes can be found in [Marshall & Oberwinkler (1999)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v401/n6756/full/401873a0.html).